# Flask-Admin+SQLAlchemy image upload works in MySQL production env but not in SQLite testcase: InterfaceError

Tags: mysql, sqlite, file-upload, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have created a web application using Flask, Flask-Admin and Flask-SQLAlchemy where the administrator can upload images. The image uploading functionality was imitated largely from [this Flask-Admin example](https://github.com/flask-admin/Flask-Admin/tree/master/examples/forms). For the production website, I use MySQL and uploading works perfectly fine. However, in the test suite I use a memory-mapped SQLite database and any attempt to upload an image through the same form fails with an `InterfaceError`. See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jgonggrijp/e09c3c2c558c16d2c2d5) for the full details and a reduced test case.

It seems like it might have something to do with type mapping, where the MySQL backend of SQLAlchemy appears to understand that the filename of the uploaded image must be inserted in the SQL statement while the SQLite backend does not. However, the Flask-Admin example that I linked to above works absolutely fine and it is based on SQLite, too.

Who can tell me what is wrong, and what needs to be done to make the test pass?

**Edit to add:** it turned out the issue was already known by the Flask-Admin developers. See [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/890).

Comment: Can you print your class where it contains SelectField() and QuerySelectField()?

Comment: @kuttyraj I don't understand your request, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. That is the reason of your problem. The problem is the difference in SQLite and MySQL backends.

As you can see in the stack trace, it's trying to bind parameter of type `FileStorage` and it fails.

```
InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: u'SELECT picture.id AS picture_id, picture.name AS picture_name, picture.path AS picture_path \nFROM picture \nWHERE picture.path = ?'] [parameters: (<FileStorage: u'openclipart_hector_gomez_landscape.png' ('image/png')>,)]
```

The place you want to put break point will be at method `do_execute()` in the `sqlalchemy.engine.default` module.

SQLite backend is a binary extension and `cursor` comes from binary extension (`_sqlite3.so`). This binary extension gets parameter of type `FileStorage` and tries to transform it to SQL representation by calling `FileStorage.__conform__()` method. But class doesn't have such method. That's why it fails.

On other hand, MySQL backend comes from pure Python module named `MySQLdb`. So it calls `MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor.execute()` method, which in particular transforms parameter of type `FileStorage` to SQL representation by calling `db.literal()`, which will end up by calling `FileStorage.__repr__()`. And you end up with the following query:

`'SELECT picture.id AS picture_id, picture.name AS picture_name, picture.path AS picture_path 
FROM picture 
WHERE picture.path = \\'<FileStorage: u\\\\'images.jpeg\\\\' (\\\\'image/jpeg\\\\')>\\''`

Unexpected, right? Now you're not so sure, that it works *correctly* with MySQL. Are you? Just try to create two pictures with the same file and you will get `Integrity error. (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'images.jpeg' for key 'path'") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO picture (name, path) VALUES (%s, %s)'] [parameters: ('Test', 'images.jpeg')]` instead of meaningful error message.

**Why does it work in the example from Flask-Admin?**

You set `unique` constraint on the `path` column of your model. That's exactly where the failing SQL query comes from. Before trying to insert new one, it checks whether picture with the same path is already exists in the database or not.

**How to fix**

The problem is a bug in `flask_admin.contrib.sqla.validators.Unique` validator or `flask_admin.form.upload.FileUploadField` (they are incompatible). Validator should use the same value, as put into model by `flask_admin.form.upload.FileUploadField.populate_obj()` method instead of directly passing `FileStorage` to database query. Just [raise an issue](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/new) on GitHub and reference this question.

I don't think it can be easily fixed in your test case, since it's quite a significant bug in a library you rely on. Of course, provided that you want to keep `unique` constraint on your `path` field.

Comment: Excellent answer, very well researched. I will submit a ticket as you suggested.